# Cannot run cgi as httpd.conf is empty!

Tags: 11.10, apache2, python-2.7, cgi

For help I checked out these links:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567432/ubuntu-apache-httpd-conf-or-apache2-conf)  [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=903386) and [This](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache2-which-conf-file-to-use-626588/)

I have an empty httpd.conf file but apache2.conf is not and the formats and tags in apache2.conf are similar to what httpd.conf has in windows as a result of which it has become a bit confusing!

I have CGI enabled and running on windows by changing the httpd.conf (of windows) file.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to enable python (2.7.3) CGI.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu Precise & the config file is /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.
This fragment:
...
    `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/`
    `<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">`
        `AllowOverride None`
        `Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`
        `Order allow,deny`
        `Allow from all`
    `</Directory>`
...
maps requested directory `cgi-bin` to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` on the server (which is where the script & template files go).

I made a Web form using a Python script 'dividerWeb1.cgi'; the HTML is:

`<form action="cgi-bin/dividerWeb1.cgi` etc....

I found this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/doityourself-it-guy/diy-enable-cgi-on-your-apache-server/1066) very useful.